# JavaFX2 - Get the ImageView of an IO-Control

Tags: java, javafx-2

I'm using JavaFX2.2. Is it actually possible to get the **ImageView** used as a parameter in the constructor for an UI-control such as Button or Label after the UI-control has been created?

I want to change the image of a control. I could probably also do it with CSS, but I'm not sure of how to use jar-resources there.

Example:

```
Label label = new Label("", new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("test.png"))));
label.getImageView().setImage(...); // there is no such method getImageView()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

((ImageView) label.getGraphic()).setImage(...)

Comment: great! It works - It says so in the documentation to [Labeled.getGraphic()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#getGraphic%28%29) but it wasn't quite obvious (optional Icon...)

Comment: Actually, graphicProperty() is a Node, so it could be anything you want. You can even put a TreeTableView inside the label or button. It is just a name - but it is not only for graphics.

Comment: So this opens quite a lot of new possibilities (better use them cautiously) - thanks!